# Escaping special characters in django-haystack query

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm trying to use Solr specific syntax with some of my django-haytack queries.  For example I'd like to search:   "state:Georgia", but haystack sends it to Solr as "state\:Georgia", breaking the query.  A Raw query can be used but it seems to need to know the field and query beforehand like so:  sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(author=Raw('state:Georgia')), but I'm not always sure beforehand what the exact field should be.  It could be state, collector, material, category or a number of others.  Does anyone know a way around this or how I can access the user's actual query?

Or perhaps I'm going down the wrong path and a custom Clean method would be in order?

Thanks